# Prefilling Tags Manager

Tags: jquery, tags

I am using

http://welldonethings.com/tags/manager

I want to prefill the tags.

I'm using something similar to below code which works fine. i.e it shows both tags Pisa and Rome

```
jQuery(".tm-input").tagsManager({
    prefilled: ["Pisa", "Rome"]
});
```

but when do this it shows only first tag. i.e garlic

```
<input 
    type="hidden" 
    name="HiddenFieldSubIngredients" 
    id="HiddenFieldSubIngredients" 
    value="garlic,onion" />
var subingredient = $("#HiddenFieldSubIngredients").val();
var subingredients = subingredient.split(',');
$(".tm-SubIngredient").tagsManager({ prefilled: [subingredients] });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You already tried with `$(".tm-SubIngredient").tagsManager({ prefilled: subingredients });` syntax?

Comment: you are right...silly me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supplying an array in an array to the plugin. Try this instead, without the square brackets:

```
$(".tm-SubIngredient").tagsManager({ prefilled: subingredients });
```